# Retrieve Standard User Information in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I have finally had some time to start playing with Haxe, i find it a great concept but i am having trouble trying to deduce how i would go about getting the current system user's name or "special folder" locations.

In my case, the User's home folder, documents folder or update folder. My target language is Java, and perhaps later C#... But i have found no real way to query the system for this information directly. All i have found so far is how to query environment variables... Which have a ton of variability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Haxe std lib does not provide such specific function. However, it doesn't prevent us to use target-specific APIs.

```
#if java
import java.lang.System;
#elseif cs
import cs.system.Environment;
import cs.system.Environment.Environment_SpecialFolder;
#end
class Test {
    static function main() {
        #if java
            //http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29
            trace(System.getProperty("user.home")); //Test.hx:11: C:\Users\Andy
        #elseif cs
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder
            trace(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment_SpecialFolder.UserProfile)); //Test.hx:14: C:\Users\Andy
        #end
    }
}
```

build.hxml:

```
-main Test
-java bin
-cmd java -jar bin/Test.jar

--next

-main Test
-cs bin
# Environment_SpecialFolder.UserProfile is available since .net 4.0
-D net-ver=40
-cmd bin\bin\Test.exe
```

Comment: i was afraid of that. So much for hoping. A friend of mine came back with the same result. I have marked your answer as correct.